# Normal operators spectral theory

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Can anyone guide me to a good resource for proving the spectral theory for normal operators and proving they admit invariant subspaces. When I google it, either it is just the finite dimensional case or are they are talking about the 'multiplication versions', which I don't want. Thanks

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem for selfadjoint operators?

Answer (score 0):

This book:

H. R. Dowson, *Spectral theory of linears operators*

has a chapter on normal operators. Some words are spent also in

Kato, *Perturbation theory for linear operators*.

I think you could find helpful Chapter 12 of

Rudin, *Functional analysis*.

Answer (score 0):

A proof of this particular version of the spectral theorem, for bounded operators appears in: 
M. Reed and B. Simon, *Methods of Mathematical Physics, Vol. I*.

If you need the case of unbounded operators, then this is a bit harder, but it appears in T. Kato, *Perturbation Theory*, K. Yosida, *Functional Analysis*.